# Show karate-summary.html in terminal after tests

Tags: karate

I'd like to view the html test summary after each test run. I'm doing this now by manually running `w3m -dump target/karate-reports/karate-summary.html | less` following a test run.

```
Feature                   Title             Passed Failed Scenarios Time
                                                                          (ms)
features/            Test end to end referral
Referral_e2e/        workflow - work in progress  1      0      1         54035
Referral_e2e.feature
                     Confirm that Business
features/SAAS-766/ Unit & Patient Identity   10     0      10        5703
SAAS-766.feature   are Required on an Accepted
                     Response
                     As an Intake team
features/SAAS-794/ member, I need to share
SAAS-794.feature   update when Patient is       4      0      4         2329
                     Admitted/ Discharged in
                     Hospice
features/SAAS-870/ Check that Referral Details  3      0      3         7899
SAAS-870.feature   are Stored in Db
```

Is there a simple way to automatically execute a terminal command like `w3m -dump target/karate-reports/karate-summary.html | less` after the new karate-summary.html report has been generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you already in a Java project. Then I recommend writing some Java code just after your unit test (typically JUnit) completes. Yes this won't work if you use the IDE actions.

You could submit a feature request, or even better contribute code. This is one of those things that possibly requires us to invent a `.karate` file for local dev env config setting etc. But as of now I don't think there's an easy out of the box way to do what you want.